# mediaelement.js Remove the black borders above and below my video?

Tags: mediaelement.js, border

I love the mediaelement.js plugin for WordPress – finally one with a loop option – thanks!

I'd like to remove the black borders that show up above and below my video as seen here:
http://wpdemo.logicadesign.com/products/bottle-closures/video/

I've played around with the height and width variables, but the black bands still show up - either on the top and bottom or on the right and left sides.

This is my HTML:

```
[video src="http://wpdemo.logicadesign.com/wp-content/uploads/bottle-plateau-Computer.m4v" poster="http://wpdemo.logicadesign.com/wp-content/uploads/bottle-plateau.jpg" preload="true" autoplay="true" loop="true" width="480" height="496"]
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here on my web app, the borders are gone when you set the width and height to be exactly the same proportion of the video.

If that doesn't help, try setting the "enableAutosize" option too.